# Green theorem application

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose that a simple closed curve $C$ in the $xy$ plane, that bounds a convex domain $D$ containing the origin. The curve is specified by $x=f(\varphi), y=g(\varphi)$ where $0\leq \varphi< 2\pi$

(a) Show that if coordinates $u$ and $\varphi$ are defined by 
$$x=uf(\varphi), y=ug(\varphi)$$
then the region $D$ is specified by the ranges $0\leq u\leq 1$ and $0\leq \varphi <2\pi$

(b) Use a), show that the area enclosed by $C$ is given by $$A=1/2\int_0^{2\pi} |f(\varphi)g'(\varphi)-f'(\varphi)g(\varphi)|d\varphi$$

For a), this is trivial, since any points inside the $C$ can be represented using $uf(\varphi)$ for $0\leq u \leq 1$ (If $D$ is convex). For b), when I use Green theorem, $$A=1/2\int xdy-ydx=1/2\int_0^{2\pi} f(\varphi)g'(\varphi)-f'(\varphi)g(\varphi)$$ 
where does the $|\cdot|$ comes from and also how could I use the convexitiy criterion

Answer (score 0):

When you're using Green's theorem to get the above formula for the area enclosed by the curve, you have to assume that the curve is oriented counterclockwise. I guess this is why the absolute value comes in, because the given parametrization doesn't specify the orientation. Consider for example the case of the unit circle where $f(\phi)=\sin\phi$ and $g(\phi)=\cos\phi$ (clockwise orientation). I think convexity is only needed in order to obtain the parametrization.